# Docker container is downed

Tags: docker, containers

After change docker directory

```
vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
========================================
{
    "graph" :"DIRECYOTY"
}
========================================
systemctl restart docker
reboot -h now

create container
$ docker run -i -t -d image /bin/bash
```

--> **container always exit**

help me please

Comment: when back to the default setting (e.g. remove grape that line)
docker operated well..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your Dockerfile? I'm going to tell you why your container always goes down without looking at it. It's probably because your container does nothing.

Suppose this is your Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update
```

This will start up, `update` and then die. But if you look at this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update

CMD sleep 120
```

This will start and live for up to 2 minutes before dying.

You probably didn't supply your Dockerfile with a `CMD` or an `ENTRYPOINT` - what is the purpose of your Dockerfile? What is it going to stay alive to do?

#### Also

If you are doing `docker run -i -t -d image /bin/bash`

I can only assume you want to run your image interactively i.e. `ssh` into your container.

Then you would do `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash`